# No encuentro el error en C

Tags: c

Basicamente intento crear una matriz, luego asignar valores enteros cada seccion de la matriz y despues separar los numero positivos y negativos en 2 vectores. Pero por algun motivo no funciona ojala alguien me ayude

(me pide que ponga mas informacion, pero no hay mas informacion asi que esto es relleno aaasdasdasudhaoisudhaisudhaiusdhauishduiashusauidashdiuashidasiiiiiiiiiiiidiuasduaiudasiudsauidashuiuqwuiwqehuiweqhieqwhieqwiueiquwihquewuqwehnuqwheioquwoeqwehouqwuehqwuoehnqouweqwhneouqwhneouqwouehqbouweqweasdasdasda)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int n,m,k=0,b=0,i,j,g;


printf("Ingrese la cantidad de filas: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("\nIngrese la cantidad de columnas: ");
scanf("%d",&m);

g=n*m;
int t[n][m],pos[g],neg[g];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        printf("Ingrese un valor: ");
        scanf("%d",&t[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        if(t[i][j] >= 0){
        pos[k] = t[i][j];
        k++;

        }
        else{
            neg[b] = t[i][j];
            b++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for(i=0;i<k;i++){
    printf("[%d]"),pos[i];
}

printf("\n\n");

  for(i=0;i<b;i++){
    printf("[%d]"),neg[i];
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Imagino que se trata de una prueba o un error, intenta editar la pregunta y añade tu código y el error para que podamos valorarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta el argumento en la funcion printf:

```
    
    printf("[%d]"),pos[i]; // Como la tienes
    printf("[%d]",pos[i]); // Como deberia estar
```

Adicionalmente te dejo este [articulo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), con el podrás hacer preguntas más elaboradas.